# python: Error with numpy.where

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to use numpy.where function as follows:

```
x= np.where(segments==1000 and segments == 0)
```

and I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Browsing through some other threads, seems this is the expected behaviour. However, I am not sure how to reformulate this using numpy.any(). I cannot get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build your condition using parenthesis and `&` or `np.logical_and` instead of `and`:

```
(segments == 1000) & (segments == 0)
```

or:

```
np.logical_and(segments == 1000, segments == 0)
```